# Custom Eclipse packages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to make an offline Eclipse installation with JDT, CDT and a few other plugins. This is what I would like to do, in decreasing preference:

- Create an installation package similar to the ones available for download on the Eclipse website. **Question:** How can this be done? How are they created? Is there some kind of automated tool that gets the packages from p2 repositories and builds them? Is there a detailed explanation somewhere of how they are created? (I am aware of Yoxos, but that is a few versions old)
- Do the installation on an internet-connected computer, and then copy the folder to another computer. **Question:** Can this be done? Will a simple Copy/Paste work correctly? Is there anything I can delete from the installation that will be automatically recreated?
- Use an Eclipse package, say JDT, and a downloaded copy (zip file?) of the CDT and other plugins, and install them on the target machine using the standard Eclipse plugin installation from a local archive method. **Question** Where can I get these downloads?

Comment: Regarding Yoxos: It is updated to the latest Indigo SR1 release, so it should be up to date. Are you looking at the right webpage? http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/ 

Is this something you are doing just for yourself or a large number of users? Different operating systems?

Comment: @Fredrik I meant the free tool. The paid one is 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach you could use is to start from the eclipse "classic" package downloaded directly from the site, and then manually install the other components you need via update manager. You can then zip the eclipse directory and distribute it without any problem.

Otherwise you could try to use [Yoxos](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/) to create your package, download and distribute it

Comment: As I said, Yoxos is not an option since that version is about 2 years old. Are you sure there is no problem just zipping it? Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, i tried it :) I distributed more than one version of eclipse by zip file. The only problem you could have is if the target plataforms are different... ie: if you are a window user and you have to distribute a version to linux user