# Remove Plug-in Development Environment in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have Eclipse standard but even that has unnecessary packages bundled and I would really like to get rid of the Plug-in Development Environment that comes packaged with the standard version. How do I go about this? Or at least disabling this package

Comment: You can try yoxos check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712757/custom-eclipse-packages

Answer (score 0):

PDE is part of the package, it can't be removed easily. If you don't want PDE then you should start with a different package that doesn't include it, or get a Platform-only build and start with that.